# p take 100% width when image deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have a `div` container with paragraphs and image i want the paragraphs to be width 100% only when image deleted only here the code:

```
<div class="dynamicPageImageConstant">
    <img alt="" src="/Upload/Images/DynamicImages/Subsea Package.jpg">
    <p> this is the paragraph</p>
</div>

.dynamicPageImageConstant {
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 96%;
}
.dynamicPageImageConstant p {
    width: 100%;
}
```

When I do that the text of the paragraph came down the image and part of it is hidden. Can I fix this with CSS or do I need jQuery?

here screen shot for the issue as more information

[image]

Comment: what is problem then?

Comment: is this `<p this is the paragraph</p>` a typo? You have not closed the `<p>` tag

Comment: Hello your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/8Vk9G/3/

Comment: You should tell us what you want to achieve. I feel like you're trying a complicated solution to an easy problem.

Comment: yes i did its only mistake in typing here but that's not the answer for my question yet

Comment: i want the <p> to be 100% width when image deleted dynamically so no blank space when there is no image in the div container

Comment: @user974946 , in fiddle  jsfiddle.net/8Vk9G/3  there is no image ,still p has 100 % width

Comment: Why not float the image on right within paragraph tag? I hope there is some other CSS styling which is affecting the way content is displayed on your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is most suitable, as its a little hard to ascertain the specifics of what you're after..but you can apply a rule to `p` tags which only follow `img` tags, to override the default for when an image is not present:

```
.DynamicPageImageContant p{ /* default p styling, e.g. with no image present */
    width: 100%;
}

.DynamicPageImageContant img + p{ /* p styling with image present */
    width: auto;
}
```

.

### **Update**: **[Accepted code:](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/8Vk9G/5/)**

HTML

```
<h1>With Image</h1>

<p class="DynamicPageImageContant">
    <img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTn_KAfHdyEKDpeGIJixdWvr_gvONoL3Pyp8P4VzyAXA3ILs0_r" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel pellentesque urna. Fusce euismod, est eget tristique mattis, arcu nibh gravida nisi, ac feugiat dui lorem id sem. Sed quis fringilla nisl, ac dignissim mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer elementum nibh eget mi malesuada ornare. Vestibulum ultrices tortor eget suscipit volutpat. Pellentesque venenatis odio sit amet est adipiscing, nec sollicitudin massa luctus. Sed tempor nibh vel pellentesque dictum. Nam porttitor laoreet bibendum.</p>

<h1>Without Image</h1>

<p class="DynamicPageImageContant">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel pellentesque urna. Fusce euismod, est eget tristique mattis, arcu nibh gravida nisi, ac feugiat dui lorem id sem. Sed quis fringilla nisl, ac dignissim mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer elementum nibh eget mi malesuada ornare. Vestibulum ultrices tortor eget suscipit volutpat. Pellentesque venenatis odio sit amet est adipiscing, nec sollicitudin massa luctus. Sed tempor nibh vel pellentesque dictum. Nam porttitor laoreet bibendum.</p>
```

CSS

```
.DynamicPageImageContant img {
    float:right;
    margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
.DynamicPageImageContant p {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but its same problem when image there the p text come down the image because its width is 100% if there is better salutation with jquery its OK

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job:

```
<div class="dynamicPageImageConstant">
    <img alt="" src="/Upload/Images/DynamicImages/Subsea Package.jpg">
    <p> this is the paragraph</p>
</div>

<style>
.dynamicPageImageConstant {
   width: 100%;
padding: 1px;
}
.dynamicPageImageConstant p, .dynamicPageImageConstant img {
    display: inline-block;
width: auto;
} 
</style>
```